# AngularJS limitTo

Tags: angularjs, slice, angularjs-limitto

Lets say that we have a some 7 records , I want to print the data based on the length of an array.
For example If the length of that array is 3 means only 3 records should be printed in first row and next set of 3 records should be printed in second row and so on...
Note : That array size will be dynamic.

How can i achieve this ?

{{consumption_data.gen}} 
           {{consumption_data.supplier_site_name}} 
           {{consumption_data.oci_site}}   
           {{consumption_data.dh_cage}} 
           {{consumption_data.contractual_pue}}  
           {{consumption_data.lower_it_load_kw}} 
           {{consumption_data.average_it_load_kw}} 
           {{consumption_data.peak_it_load_kw}} 
           {{consumption_data.total_contracted_load_kw}} 
           {{consumption_data.load}} 
           {{consumption_data.contractual_pue_as_per_table}}

I have tried slice but only for the first row the data is coming correctly

Comment: It might help to include more code to get an idea of what you are expecting. Are we talking about groupings via ngRepeat? Are subsequent records coming over via AJAX calls? How is your array dynamic? As in, will this controller/component instance never have any predictable data structure?